# Trying to complete an exercise and make a ball move from left to right then reverse

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="ball" style="
  z-index:5;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:200px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:black"></div>

<script>

var velocity = 100;
var positionX = 0;
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
let reverse = false



if (reverse = true){
  function moveBall(){
  positionX = positionX + velocity;
  ball.style.left = (positionX + 'px')}
}

if (reverse = false){
  function moveBall(){
  positionX = positionX - velocity;
  ball.style.left = (positionX + 'px')}
}



var Xmin = 0;
var Xmax = 300;

if (ball.style.left = Xmax){
  reverse = true
}
if (ball.style.left = Xmin){
  reverse = false
}
setInterval(moveBall, 100)

</script>
```

The ball should movefrom left to right, then reverse. With the edges between Xmin and Xmax.

This the instructions I have.

Define a global variable called reverse and set its value to false. This variable is a boolean (can either be true or false) and it will help you define which direction the ball should move in.
The reverse variable will change value every time the ball hits the edge of a defined area on the screen.
The area is defined by the variables Xmin and Xmax.
Inside the moveBall() function, add logic to set the ball position on the x-axis based on the value of reverse:
When reverse is false, the ball moves from left to right (ball position + velocity.)
When reverse is true, the ball moves from left to right (ball position - velocity.)
After that, inside the moveBall() function, add logic to compare the variable positionX, Xmin and Xmax.
if the ball position (positionX) is greater than Xmax or equals Xmin, then the value of reverse should be switched.

I completed the ball moving from left to right. However, I'm stuck trying to reverse it.

Comment: This question looks like it's about JavaScript, yet has the [java] tag. It's important to understand the difference between those two languages.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the velocity by `-1` when a boundary is reached.

```js
let velocity = 100;
let positionX = 0;
const ball = document.getElementById('ball');
const Xmin = 0;
const Xmax = 300;
setInterval(() => {
  positionX = Math.max(Xmin, Math.min(Xmax, positionX + velocity));
  ball.style.left = positionX + 'px';
  if (positionX === Xmin || positionX === Xmax) velocity *= -1;
}, 100);
```

```html
<div id="ball" style="z-index:5;position:absolute;left:0;top:50px;width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50%;background:#000"></div>
```

Also note that `requestAnimationFrame` is more appropriate here than `setInterval`.